# wordpress menu nav archive dropdown link

Tags: php, wordpress

Am trying to add a dropdown archive menu for my wordpress site.
I have been trying to follow the wordpress codex and i can get it to work but i dont know how to get it inside my menu i have in wordpress.

I have made a function for it but am not totaly sure i understand how to write the ' and " proper.

```
function wp_menu_archive( $args ) {


 $args = '<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value=""> echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ); </option> 
  wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); 
</select>';

 return $items . = <li>  $args  </li> ;

 }
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wp_menu_archive', 52, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `$args` and then returning empty `$items` ?

Change `$args` with `$items` ,

```
function wp_menu_archive( $items ) {

 $archives  = '<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value=""> ' . esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ) . ' </option> ' ;

   $archives .=  wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 
    'format' => 'option',
    'echo' => 0,
    'show_post_count' => 1 ) 
        );
 $archives .= '</select>';

 return $items .=  $archives ;

 }
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wp_menu_archive', 52, 2 );
```

I do not remember now exactly the output of `wp_get_archives` , but that should work .

( Also all your concatenation syntax was wrong ..)

**EDIT**

ok, I am sorry, checking the code now , you need one more argument in the `wp_get_archives()` which is `'echo' => 0,` . I updated the code . ( we need `return`, not direct `echo` )

Comment: THank you so much for the help but it seems like its a syntax error in that code. i think its in the last 3 lines. (first i tought it was  'show_post_count' => 1 that should be  'show_post_count' => '1' but that dident help.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have accessto server now nor to source . But delete the space between the `.`and the `=` on the last two lines of function :-)

Comment: Right .. I wonder when you will finish that mega - menu of yours. I hope at least you will show it to us.. :-)

Comment: haha, of course i will show but it will take some time i have a few more questions but i feel bad to spam them so i try for a few days to solve it and learn. I would give you a sneakpeak if there was a PM function here.